# XCode 8 - How to solve an Auto resizing issue on XCode version 8.0?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, ios10, xcode8

I used XCode version 7.2.1 for my project. But I updated the XCode version 8.0 now. Though the scroll view is messed in view controllers of my project. Here I have used Resizing only not an Auto layout. I referred many forums. But can't able to find a solution for that. Here I have attached similar links to what I had tried.

[Xcode 8 GM seed Storyboard layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394316/xcode-8-gm-seed-storyboard-layout-issue)

[Layout issues after updating to Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8)

[I have to update frame of everything in storyboard every time I start Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279306/i-have-to-update-frame-of-everything-in-storyboard-every-time-i-start-xcode)

What is the exact solution for Scroll view resizing issue in XCode version 8.0?

Comment: I too have a same problem, My scrollview subviews are not resizing properly, Waiting for someone valuable answer.

Comment: Mee too facing same problem, did u solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked to Apple about this same issue, and they have sent the following message to my inbox:

> Hello Raja,
>
> Engineering has determined that your bug report (28489404) and will be closed.

Comment: That does not make a great deal of sense. "Engineering has determined that your bug report" is what, exactly? I think this is missing some words.

Answer (score 1):

**Its work for me**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770664/6619234 you can try this...

after Save & Close don't open this xib/Storyboard....it is an temporary solution....till the apple fix it..

Comment: @Raja Sorry but its working for me fine.....but this is temporary solution.

Comment: Its okay. Which version of IDE will you using now?

Answer (score 1):

Apple just came out with XCode 8.2, which fixes this problem for me. I have been using XCode 7.3.1 for my interface design parallel to 8.1, but I can now use 8.2 without any problems.

The storyboard gets updated with widths and height of frames though, to accommodate the new 'View as:' functionality. Though it doesn't seem to affect running on device/simulator.

Curiously, the bugfix it is not noted in the [XCode 8.2 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW9).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the same by selecting my xib files and then I selected my view in the xib after that I went to attribute inspector and changed the size, status bar, top bar and bottom bar as inferred and it worked but before that xocode pointed out I am missing 2x retina display file so I clicked the warning and it was added automatically.