# Height and Y position values changed by .5 in storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, height, frame, difference

I'm working on an iOS project in Xcode (7.3) together with a colleague of mine. Lately we've noticed a weird thing occurring in storyboard files.

Every time my colleague - let's call him Erik - opens a storyboard file, some UI elements' y and height values are incremented by 0.5.

### Example

Rect prior to Erik's entrance:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="527" height="43"/>
```

Rect post Erik's entrance:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="527" height="43.5"/>
```

It's not a biggie but it causes an unwished diff in git every time we've opened a storyboard file.

Do you know what we can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any insight in the answers, but there's a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598115/interface-builder-degrades-storyboards-resizes-and-repositions-views-in-small-i